# Error installing TA-Lib for Anaconda

Tags: python, mingw, anaconda, ta-lib

I am running Python 3.4.1 Anaconda 2.1.0 on Win7 x64. Cython version is 0.21 and I can confirm it has been installed.

I am trying to install the TA-lib wrapper via the command `easy_install TA-lib`.

I already have the ta-lib folder in `c:\ta-lib`.

This is the full print out of what happens:

> easy_install ta-lib
> Searching for ta-lib
> Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/ta-lib/
> Reading http://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib
> Reading https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib/releases
> Best match: TA-Lib 0.4.8
> Downloading https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib/archive/TA_Lib-0.4.8.zip
> Processing TA_Lib-0.4.8.zip
> Writing C:\Users\ULYATES\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-mxydk494\ta-lib-TA_Lib-0.4.8\setup.cfg
> Running ta-lib-TA_Lib-0.4.8\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir C:\Users\ULYATES\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-mxydk494\ta-lib-TA_Lib-0.4.8\egg-dist-tmp-dvmbdia1
>
> c:/anaconda3/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:\ta-lib\c\lib/ta_libc_cdr.lib when   searching for -lta_libc_cdr
> c:/anaconda3/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:\ta-lib\c\lib/ta_libc_cdr.lib when   searching for -lta_libc_cdr
> c:/anaconda3/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:\ta-lib\c\lib\ta_libc_cdr.lib when   searching for -lta_libc_cdr
> c:/anaconda3/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lta_libc_cdrcollect2.exe: error: ld returned 1   exit status
> error: Setup script exited with error: command 'C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\gcc.bat' failed with exit status 1

Answer (score 12):

I have plagued by this for the past few days, and almost immediately after I posted this I figured it out.

I just installed TA_Lib-0.4.8-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

now everything works great.

Hope this helps someone.

Regards,

Sean

Comment: Works with winpython 64bit, too. This saved me from more headache then I already had getting nowhere with ta-lib. Thanks!

Comment: How do you install these files from the URL?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you got your ta-lib build but I'm guessing you're using the binary from sourceforge in the ta-lib-0.4.0-msvc.zip file.  It's 32-bit.  You'd need to use a 32-bit python / anaconda to use it.